# Is there a way to create sections in pytest HTML report?

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests, pytest, pytest-html

I have 135 Test Cases (and growing), and I can't seem to figure out how I can divide my test cases into different sections.
For example, I want my regression test cases to be part of a separate table, and stats test cases to be part of a separate table instead of a single long table. How would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using allure reporting
https://docs.qameta.io/allure/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I cannot use allure reports, as I have to send the report as an Email, and there is no easy way to do so with Allure. 
I cannot use this [https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service#customize-emailable-report] docker approach, since my work app requires that Hyper-V be disabled (which is a requirement for docker to run).